# Tomcat 7 memory usage - what keeps it growing?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

Good evening,

I've got an Apache Tomcat 7 running, with a little jsp for testing. Essentially, it just prints a few lines.
Then, I've got a plain html file with some text in it.

My question is:
If I siege my Tomcat with ab it grows in memory, nothing special here.
But the memory usage grows and grows without stopping. Moreover, it doesn't release it after a while. This happens with the jsp and the html.

Whats the reason for this behaviour?

Best regards

Comment: What memory limit have you set for your Tomcat java process?

Comment: @Robert: Standard 64 MB, I tried adjusting it, but no luck.

Comment: What tool indicates that the memory usage grows? And on what operating system are you running Tomcat? Are you using the Tomcat native library?

Comment: It's also worth increasing the PermGen size.

Comment: @Codo: I use top, free and ps, running on Debian 5. APR is used. It really looks like the problem is something native, because I don't get any out of memory exceptions, jmap also reports low java memory usage.

Answer (score 3):

As @Bozho said its very likely a leak in code.
Use jmap to see who is eating up so much of space.

```
jmap -histo:live <tomcat java process id>
```

This will show you which types of objects occupying how much memory in heap, that should give you idea which code to look into.

Comment: If it keeps growing, it can't be the Java heap since the heap is limited (e.g. to 64 MB). So if it grows and grows and you don't get an _out of memory_ exception, then it must be a native library.